# How to make TortoiseGit not open SVG files with image compare tool

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have an svg file in Git and I want to see a diff of local changes. I would expect the config setting for which files are opened with TortoiseGitIDiff to be in TortoiseGit settings/Diff Viewer/Advanced, but there is no entry for .svg there. Where is this association made and how do I change it?

Comment: Have you tried setting an alternative diff tool using the advanced settings (i.e., just add .svg)?

Comment: I don't know what to fill in there. The existing ones call out to wscript. There must be some other point where the decision is made what tool to use though? Otherwise it wouldn't be able to know if it should use TortoiseGitIDiff for svg.

Comment: Click on Help or Press F1, https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-Progs-Adv

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but it doesn't help me. There is, somehow, a reason why it uses TortoiseGitIDiff instead of the regular diff tool for svg files. Everything, including the documentation you link to, leads me to think that this is how and where this decision is made. But apparently it's not.

Comment: Please include exactly what you did in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The defaults for images are hard-coded in TortoiseGit source code (cf. https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/blob/28d2301c16d78ac94f33e996cf606fa10bd830da/src/TortoiseProc/AppUtils.cpp#L279).

You can easily set up a different tool by just adding e.g. ".svg" in the [TortoiseGit settings/Diff Viewer/Advanced dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-Progs-Adv).

Comment: Thanks, that link allowed me to cobble together the command line I think I need: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe" /base:"%base" /mine:"%mine" /merged:"%merged" /basename:"%bname" /theirsname:"%tname" /minename:"%yname" /mergedname:"%mname" /saverequired
Except that this still doesn't work, it just shows TortoiseGitMerge with the dialog to select two files to compare. I've tried various variations of this, all with the same result.